# HTTP GET setting internal data, still considered RESTful?

Tags: rest, http, get, restful-architecture

As I understand it, a HTTP GET request should return the requested data and is considered RESTful if safe (read-only) and idempotent (no side effects).

However, I would like to implement a service to show new items since last visit using an URI of `/items/userid/new`, can that in any way be RESTful?

When returning the data, the items sent in response to the GET request should be marked as read in order to keep track of what is new. Marking these items will violate both the safe requirement and the idempotent requirement.

Does that mean `.../new` is never considered RESTful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very interesting question. I think the answer would be "depends on the implementation" since there are different solutions that would all meet the business requirement.

If every visit to the URL `/items/userid/new` by the same user modifies the DB records, then it's not a "safe method" and would not fit the commonly accepted REST pattern.

If you're filtering for the new items on the view, but without any corresponding DB changes with each GET call, then it would certainly be RESTful. For example:

```
/items/userid/new?lastvisit=2015-12-31
```

or

```
/items/userid/new?last_id=12345
```

or storing the list of viewed items on the client side would certainly qualify.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we decide the restful service and associate protocol methods to it. In case of HTTP it is we use GET,POST,PUT...etc. Normally Get is used get some application state that will rendered with hyper text.

Here `/items/userid/new` can be new service that returns the list. Any modification on this list will be subsequent request with different method association.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping track of already visited items should not be the server's responsibility. The client should rember already visited items. That leads to better scalability and loosy coupled systems as the server must not handle these parameters for e.g. thousand of clients.

To deliver fresh items you could, as Cahit already touched, provide a feed that includes all items for either a time frame or a fixed number of items. Generally an [archived feed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005) is a good choice.

As a result of this a client can crawl your feed on its own to retrieve all new items.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question indeed.

For a plain url, I would not do it. One reason for example: I remember sending a testmail with a unique link pointing to our own webserver. While passing through the ISP's mailserver, a request was made with that url to our server.. This was done by a spamfilter to check if the url existed.. So, if a mail was sent to the customer saying '*look here for the new items*', those would be gone even before the mail was received.

And you certainly wouldn't want that plain url to appear in search results somewhere, or be used for *preloading* pages.

On the other hand, if the request was made during login (or using a cookie), it *could* be ok.

Maybe that's what SO does when we view our statistics/responses.